# Symfony Security AdvancedUserInterface

Tags: php, symfony, security

Welcome,
I have some problem with user Authentication. My security.yml file:

```
security:
    firewalls:
          default:
             anonymous: ~
             http_basic: ~
             provider: our_db_provider
             logout:
                  path:   /logout

     providers:
          our_db_provider:
              entity:
                  class: CmsUserBundle:User
                  property: username

     encoders:
         Cms\UserBundle\Entity\User: plaintext
```

My user entity:

```
<?php
  namespace Cms\UserBundle\Entity;

  use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
  use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;
  use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

 /**
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Cms\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 */
 class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
 {
  /**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
 */
private $username;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length= 64)
 */
private $email;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date", length=128)
 */
private $dateOfBirthday;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 */
private $about;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
 */
private $salt;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Cms\UserBundle\Entity\Role")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $roles;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $eraseCredentials;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean",  options={"default": 0})
 */
private $isActive;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 * @Assert\Image()
 */
private $profilePicturePath;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 */
private $activatedHash;


public function __construct()
{
    $this->setActivatedHash(bin2hex(random_bytes(36)));
}

public function getSalt()
{
    return $this->salt;
}

public function getPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

public function getRoles()
{
    return array($this->roles);
}

public function eraseCredentials()
{

}

public function getUsername()
{
    return $this->username;
}

/**
 * Get eraseCredentials
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getEraseCredentials()
{
    return $this->eraseCredentials;
}

/**
 * Set isActive
 *
 * @param boolean $isActive
 * @return User
 */
public function setIsActive($isActive)
{
    $this->isActive = $isActive;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get isActive
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function getIsActive()
{
    return $this->isActive;
}


/**
 * Set email
 *
 * @param string $email
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setEmail($email)
{
    $this->email = $email;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get email
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set username
 *
 * @param string $username
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setUsername($username)
{
    $this->username = $username;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Set password
 *
 * @param string $password
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password = $password;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Set dateOfBirthday
 *
 * @param \DateTime $dateOfBirthday
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setDateOfBirthday($dateOfBirthday)
{
    $this->dateOfBirthday = $dateOfBirthday;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get dateOfBirthday
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getDateOfBirthday()
{
    return $this->dateOfBirthday;
}

/**
 * Set about
 *
 * @param string $about
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setAbout($about)
{
    $this->about = $about;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get about
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getAbout()
{
    return $this->about;
}

/**
 * Set salt
 *
 * @param string $salt
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setSalt($salt)
{
    $this->salt = $salt;

    return $this;
}


/**
 * Set eraseCredentials
 *
 * @param string $eraseCredentials
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setEraseCredentials($eraseCredentials)
{
    $this->eraseCredentials = $eraseCredentials;

    return $this;
}


/**
 * Set roles
 *
 * @param \Cms\UserBundle\Entity\Role $roles
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setRoles(\Cms\UserBundle\Entity\Role $roles = null)
{
    $this->roles = $roles;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Set profilePicturePath
 *
 * @param string $profilePicturePath
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setProfilePicturePath($profilePicturePath)
{
    $this->profilePicturePath = $profilePicturePath;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get profilePicturePath
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getProfilePicturePath()
{
    return $this->profilePicturePath;
}

/**
 * Serialization is required to FileUploader
 * @return string
 */
public function serialize()
{
    return serialize(array(
        $this->id,
        $this->username,
        $this->salt,
        $this->password,
        $this->roles,
        $this->isActive
    ));
}

/**
 * @param string $serialized
 */
public function unserialize($serialized)
{
    list (
        $this->id,
        $this->username,
        $this->salt,
        $this->password,
        $this->roles,
        $this->isActive
        ) = unserialize($serialized);
}

/**
 * Set activatedHash
 *
 * @param string $activatedHash
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setActivatedHash($activatedHash)
{
    $this->activatedHash = $activatedHash;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get activatedHash
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getActivatedHash()
{
    return $this->activatedHash;
}


public function isAccountNonExpired()
{
    return true;
}

public function isAccountNonLocked()
{
      return true;
}


public function isCredentialsNonExpired()
{
   return true;
}

public function isEnabled()
{
   return $this->getIsActive();
}
```

}

And in my Controller:

```
  $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($foundUser, $foundUser->getPassword(), 'default', array($role->getRole()) );
                    $this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);
```

My problem is that every time user is success Authenticated, even if my `isEnabled()` function return false. Thanks for help.

Comment: From where `$role` come from in `$role->getRole()`?

Comment: It is other Entity where I collect my role list. It return `ROLE_ADMIN` in this example. In controller `$role =  $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('CmsUserBundle:Role')->findBy(array('id' => $foundUser->getRoles()))[0];`

Comment: Can somebody help me?